# Compute a cohomology group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

How can I compute the cohomology group $H^1(X,\mathcal O)$ (the sheaf $\mathcal O$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions and $X$ is a compact Riemann surface) ? I know $H^1(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O) = 0$ but I have no ideas in other case. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you know the Dolbeault isomorphism $H^1(X,\mathscr O) \cong H^{0,1}(X)$?

Comment: I read a bit about it but I don't remember very well for be honnest. Is $H^{0,1}(X)$ easy to compute ?

Comment: Since $X$ is a compact Kähler manifold, $H^1(X,\Bbb C) \cong H^{1,0}(X)\oplus H^{0,1}(X)$ and $H^{1,0}(X) \cong \overline{H^{0,1}(X)}$, so dimensions follow from what you know about the  standard cohomology/homology of surfaces of genus $g$.

Comment: Oh you're right thanks ! So I guess I need to read about this Dolbeault isomorphism. Many thanks again !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to compute this for some special curve, and note that this is a deformation invariant, so the answer will be the same for all curves of the same genus.

For a special curve, one can take a hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$. It is a double cover of $P^1$ branched in $2g + 2$ points. Thus, if $s \in H^0(P^1,O(2g+2))$ is the section that vanishes in these points, then one can write $X$ as
$$
X = Spec_{P^1}(O \oplus O(-1-g)),
$$
where the algebra structure is given by the map $O(-1-g) \otimes O(-1-g) \cong O(-2-2g) \stackrel{s}\to O$. Then
$$
H^1(X,O_X) = H^1(P^1,O \oplus O(-1-g)) = H^1(P^1,O(-1-g))
$$
has dimension $g$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Sorry for the naive question but what is $Spec_{P^1}(...)$ ? Does it mean is it a $P^1$ bundle with fiber the projectivisation of $O \oplus O(-1-g)$ ?

Comment: @rain: It is a relative spectrum of a sheaf of algebras. For each affine open take the spectrum of the sections of this sheaf over this open, then glue these local charts by the natural gluing maps.

Comment: If the holomorphic function $\Omicron $ is replaced by meromorphic function $\mathfrak{M} $ ? Please describe. @Sasha.

Comment: If the holomorphic function $\mathfrak{O} $ is replaced by meromorphic function $\mathfrak{M} $ ? It is also true for meromorphic functions. Please describe.